# Whats the name of this OST track from the Toaru Majutsu/Railgun Series

Tags: music, a-certain-magical-index, a-certain-scientific-railgun

Sorry, not sure if this is the best place to ask this.

The OST track starts out with a long whistle, followed by quick whistles blows, and it was quite fast (not slow/sad) (kinda had a sporty feel?).

The whistle sound effect sounded a lot like the one in the background of this OST track: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VGWlk745yr0

I recalled it was from the Toaru Majutsu/Railgun Series, but i might be recalling wrongly, so if you know of a OST track that sounds similar, please let me know.

Thank you.

Comment: Please check out https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4054/how-to-ask-a-music-identification-question and provide what language you watched the show in and what episode(s) it is from, if you know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it, it was code break from the Mahouka Koukou no Rettousei series